Given that a homogenous system of linear equation in three variable has a non trivial solution, evaluate the following expression.
The Question
Given that the following homogeneous equation in three variable has a non trivial solution:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{ccc}
a x +  y +  z &=& 0 \\
 x + b y +  z &=& 0 \\
 x + y + c z &=& 0 \\
\end{array}
\end{equation*}
Then evaluate $\frac{1}{1-a}+\frac{1}{1-b}+\frac{1}{1-c}$
Attempt
Since the system has a non trivial solution, the determinant of the coefficient matrix is $0$, which yields the expression: $abc-(a+b+c)+2 = 0.$ But I am not able to algebraically manipulate it to get the  value of the required expression. Please help.

So, it turns out, if one just evaluates the given expression, one gets:
$\frac{3-2(a+b+c)+bc+ac+ab}{1-(a+b+c)+ab+bc+ca -abc}$. Now, replace $abc$ in the denominator by $a+b+c-2$, and then the Numerator and Denominator will be same. Thanks to a previous question.

An infinite loop
